# How to do Incremental MapReduce in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

In CouchDB and system designs like [Incoop](https://www.mpi-sws.org/tr/2011-003.pdf), there's a concept called "Incremental MapReduce" where results from previous executions of a MapReduce algorithm are saved and used to skip over sections of input data that haven't been changed.

Say I have 1 million rows divided into 20 partitions. If I run a simple MapReduce over this data, I could cache/store the result of reducing each separate partition, before they're combined and reduced again to produce the final result. If I only change data in the 19th partition then I only need to run the map & reduce steps on the changed section of the data, and then combine the new result with the saved reduce results from the unchanged partitions to get an updated result. Using this sort of catching I'd be able to skip almost 95% of the work for re-running a MapReduce job on this hypothetical dataset.

Is there any good way to apply this pattern to Spark? I know I could write my own tool for splitting up input data into partitions, checking if I've already processed those partitions before, loading them from a cache if I have, and then running the final reduce to join all the partitions together. However, I suspect that there's an easier way to approach this.

I've experimented with checkpointing in Spark Streaming, and that is able to store results between restarts, which is almost what I'm looking for, but I want to do this outside of a streaming job.

RDD caching/persisting/checkpointing almost looks like something I could build off of - it makes it easy to keep intermediate computations around and reference them later, but I think cached RDDs are always removed once the SparkContext is stopped, even if they're persisted to disk. So caching wouldn't work for storing results between restarts. Also, I'm not sure if/how checkpointed RDDs are supposed to be loaded when a new SparkContext is started... They seem to be stored under a [UUID in the checkpoint directory](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2327) that's specific to a single instance of the SparkContext.

Answer (score 1):

Both use cases suggested by the [article](https://www.mpi-sws.org/tr/2011-003.pdf) (incremental logs processing and incremental query processing) can be generally solved by Spark Streaming.

The idea is that you have incremental updates coming in using DStreams abstraction. Then, you can process new data, and join it with previous calculation either using time window based processing or using arbitrary stateful operations as part of [Structured Stream Processing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html). Results of the calculation can be later dumped to some sort of external sink like database or file system, or they can be exposed as an SQL table.

If you're not building an online data processing system, regular Spark can be used as well. It's just a matter of how incremental updates get into the process, and how intermediate state is saved. For example, incremental updates can appear under some path on a distributed file system, while intermediate state containing previous computation joined with new data computation can be dumped, again, to the same file system.

Comment: I could use streaming for a dataset that I only ever append to, but imagine I update a single row at a random point in the dataset. I would either need to clear out my old state and reprocess everything, or come up with a clever way of removing whatever the old row added to the state before adding the updated new row. For simple things like counters that's fine, but for more complex operations it might be impossible to account for a change without reprocessing.

Comment: Unless you mean that each time window has its own results stored separately, such that I could redo the processing for a single time window and then update the result of joining all those time windows together. That would be close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @slang `mapGroupsWithState` function allows arbitrary state update, have a look at [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html) article for an example.

Comment: Ok, but my data aren't really "events". They're more like documents and they can be updated or deleted. If I only used state updates I would need to make sure that every operation I use to aggregate my data can also be reversed if a document is deleted, which is a major constraint. What I'd like to be able to do is just drop a certain section of the state that was produced by the document that got updated/deleted and reprocess all the documents that were in that section. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: I would recommend rethinking your data modelling - often in distributed systems it's useful to model command-events and build a separate query handler on a document-view ("CQRS").

Comment: In what way could I model this such that the update problem isn't an issue?